# TCGABiolinks: GDCprepare never terminates and crashes

Tags: r, crash, bioconductor

I recently started using TCGAbiolinks to process some gene expression from the TCGA database. All I need to do is download the data into an R file, and there are many examples online. However, every time I try the example codes, it crashes my R workspace and sometimes my PC entirely.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
library(TCGAbiolinks)

queryLUAD <- GDCquery(project = "TCGA-LUAD",
                      data.category = "Transcriptome Profiling",
                      data.type = "Gene Expression Quantification",
                      sample.type = "Primary Tumor",
                      legacy = FALSE,
                      workflow.type = "HTSeq - FPKM-UQ"
                      )

GGDCdownload(queryLUAD)

LUADRNAseq <- GDCprepare(queryLUAD,
                         save = TRUE,
                         save.filename = "LUAD.R")
```

As you can see, it's very simple and (as far as I can tell, identical) to examples like this [one](https://rdrr.io/bioc/TCGAbiolinks/man/GDCprepare.html).

When I run this code, it downloads fully (I've checked the folder with the files). Then, I run GDCprepare. The progress bar starts and goes to 100%. Then, the command never terminates eventually either RStudio or my machine crashes.

Here's the terminal output:

```
> GDCdownload(queryLUAD)
Downloading data for project TCGA-LUAD
Of the 533 files for download 533 already exist.
All samples have been already downloaded
> LUADRNAseq <- GDCprepare(queryLUAD,
+                          save = TRUE,
+                          save.filename = "LUAD.R")
|==============================================================================================|100%                      Completed after 13 s
```

Although it says completed, it never does. To solve this, I've tried reinstalling TCGAbiolinks, updating R to the latest version, and even running it on an entirely different machine (a Mac instead of Windows). I've tried other datasets ("LUSC") and got the exact same behavior. Nothing has solved the issue, and I haven't found this issue mentioned anywhere online.

I am sincerely grateful for any and all advice on why this is happening and how I can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Experienced exactly the same problem. Tried a variety of things, and noticed it doesn't crash when dataset has less than 100 samples or running with "summarizedExperiment = FALSE" for dataset less than 300 samples.

Comment: My datasets were each over 500 samples, so that would be in line with your findings. Thankfully I found a site to directly download a .csv with the data, although it wasn't nearly as efficient as the TCGABiolinks approach

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue here. Looks like there is some kind of a memory leak happening because my RAM usage goes to 100%. I managed to "GDCprepare" 500 samples without crashing with ~64GB RAM but even after finishing, the memory is still occupied by the R session, even if I try garbage collection and removing everything in the environment.

I didn't have this issue with TCGAbiolinks around a year ago...

Comment: I couldn't GDCPrepare my datasets of around 500 samples, but my RAM is only 16 GB, which could explain the different behavior. Thanks for checking the memory usage